# dafny output as SMT file

Tags: z3, smt, dafny

I successfully wrote a verified Dafny program that given an integer array, returns the length of the longest monotone prefix. The permalink is [here](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/MBTeV). I want to be able to examine the SMT file Dafny used, even though there were no errors. I tried various flag options like:

```
$ dafny example_longest_monotone.dfy /useSmtOutputFormat /printModelToFile:smt_file.smt
```

But none seem to work? Am I wrong thinking that there **must be some underlying SMT query that returned `unsat`** in the case where Dafny succeeds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line flag to output the prover input is `/proverLog:<file>`.

You can also print the Boogie file that Dafny produces using `/print:<file>`.