# assertion violation in MVS with Dafny , but it is verified in rise4fun

Tags: dafny

https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/ZkKN

This assertion is not verified by Dafny 2.3.0. over MVS, but it is verfied in rise4fun, of course with a warning about triggers. It causes "Verification inconclusive".

Moreover, https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/Um6t does not print "hello" (is not running) in rise4fun. It should be some error since there is no "assertion violation".
Please, some help?

Comment: Both files seem to time out. How did you determine the first is verified in rise4fun?

The time out is also the reason that "hello" isn't being printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your program verifies when I add the `-arith:2` flag, which adds symbolic synonyms for the arithmetic symbols and allows them to be used in triggers.

**Edit:**
A more general answer is that your problem uses nonlinear arithmetic, which is in general undecidable. There are some tips on how to handle those in the FAQ at https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/FAQ, I don't have much experience with Dafny and nonlinear arithmetic myself, however.

I don't know why your file has worked before, but to investigate you could print the SMT encoding Dafny feeds to Z3 (see [dafny output as SMT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025807/dafny-output-as-smt-file/57237474#57237474)) and compare different versions, if there's no difference, maybe there's a difference between Z3 versions.

Maybe there's a way to encode your problem differently, that works in a more stable manner between different solver versions, assuming there's no bug in any of the tools.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a new comment before reading this. Thank you for this help.

Comment: Thank you Mathias for this help. Indeed the flag works in all my examples. But I should say that previous versions of Dafny didn't need any flag to verify this kind of assertions.

Comment: Sorry but in https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/Um6t the flag DOES NOT SOLVE THE PROBLEM

Comment: Thanks again for your help and suggestions. Sorry for the insistence, but please have a look to this: https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/v6pN. The flag doesn't not work.

Comment: Is `method {arith:2} ...` valid Dafny? It works when you call `dafny -arith:2 <yourfile>`

Comment: It is syntactically correct, the parser does not complain.

Comment: Here https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/hzt9  you can find a solution that Rustan Leino suggested to me (years ago), but I would like to have something easier for my students in the most recent version of Dafny. Some kind of flag working in MVS or so.

Comment: Adding an opaque function like that should be equivalent to using the `-arith` flag. You can try introducing such functions for all arithmetic operators.

Comment: In addition, I am suspecting an error because in the following https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/Y03M the first assertion is true, but the commented one is violated. Please, uncomment it and check.

Comment: In your last example, the statements differ. Consider `t = 2`, `e = 1`. Can you explain why you think the statement should hold? I don't have time to look into it in depth right now.

Comment: Yes, they are different, but one is a consequence of the other.  Indeed, the second one is stronger, I wrongly think that the strongest was the first one. To realize it  you should note that   (a ==> ((b && c) || (!b && d) )) ==> (a ==>( (b && c) || (d))), and the second one is of the form (a ==> ((b && c) || (!b && d) )) , whereas the first one is  (a ==> ((b && c) || (!b && d) )), apart from universal closure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200907/discussion-between-paqui-lucio-and-matthias-schlaipfer).

Comment: Coming back to my original problem, which was not related to the auxiliary lemma, I find something I cannot figure out. The assertions in rise4fun.com/Dafny/9fAslB make me think that something is not going well. The verifier has a strange behavior. Please, uncomment exactly one at each test. There is something related to nat, but I think that it is not related to induction.

Comment: I experience a bit different behavior than you, but when I add `-arith:2` all of them verify.

Comment: In my case, using {:arith 2} after the keyword assert or after the keyword method (both are admitted in Dafny 2.3.0), all except one are verified, but the most intriguing issue is that this one is the simplest one:                            assert {:arith 2} forall b,e,x,t,p ::
       (0 <= t <= e && p * power(x,t) == power(b,e) && t > 0 )
    ==> (0 <= t-1 <= e && p * x * power(x,t-1) == power(b,e)); It also fails in rise4fun.

Comment: I think that `{:arith 2}` has no effect. At least it does not in my Dafny version. You can check that by generating the smt2 file using `-proverLog:<smt2file>` with and without `{:arith 2}` added to the assertion and running `diff` on the files.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why this happens in this case , indeed some non-verified assertions in my previous examples were verified when I add the flag {:arith 2}. Thank you again.